# React thinks my "AbstractContract" is an "Object" and wont render when I call a method

Tags: reactjs, json, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

I am following a tutorial on how to make a react app using the Ethereum block chain. I have my own local blockchain to test on and I have added my contract to it successfully.
Now, I am wanting to pull some information from a method in that contract and display it using react.
However, when I grab the contract and set the state, react is returning an object instead of an "AbstractContract". Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
    class App extends Component {
        componentWillMount() {
            this.loadBlockchainData()
        }

        async loadBlockchainData() {
            //grabbing the MetaMask network data
            const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "http://localhost:7545")
            const network = await web3.eth.net.getNetworkType()
            console.log("network:", network)

            //pulling the wallet/accounts from MetaMask
            const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
            console.log("account:", accounts[0]);
            this.setState({ account: accounts[0] })

           //Grabbing the contract info from blockchain
           const todoList = new web3.eth.Contract(TODO_LIST_ABI, TODO_LIST_ADDRESS)
           console.log("List address", TODO_LIST_ADDRESS)
           console.log("List add", todoList.address)
           console.log("todoList", todoList)
           this.setState({todoList})

           //Calling Methods from Contract
           const taskCount = await todoList.methods.taskCount().call()
           console.log("taskCount", taskCount)
           this.setState({taskCount})
       }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
    account: '',
    taskCount: 0
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        <p>Your account: {this.state.account}</p>
    <p>Your Task Count: {this.state.taskCount}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the returned logs:

```
return address is :0xBcA4622f7dC5205cf08454cE27B87966286184d2
todoList: 
Object { providerResolver: {…}, givenProvider: Proxy, _currentProvider: {…}, _defaultAccount: undefined, _defaultBlock: "latest", _transactionBlockTimeout: 50, _transactionConfirmationBlocks: 24, _transactionPollingTimeout: 750, _defaultGasPrice: undefined, _defaultGas: undefined, … }

taskCount:
Object { _hex: "0x01", … }
```

The issue:
todoList is supposed to be a "AbstractContract"
taskCount starts as 0, but it should be 1 since a task is created when the contract is executed.

The Error thrown:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_hex}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Where is the `render`? That is where the error is being thrown isn't it?

Comment: Are `AbstractContract`s react components?

Comment: I added the rest of the class showing the "componentWillMount" which from what i understand renders the Async Blockchain info. The the tutorial, they had the "todoList" returning an "AbstractContract" instead of an "object" so I assume that it is a react component.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by re-running it after copying, deleting, and pasting my code back in. It's still not showing the "AbstractContract" but everything how its supposed to.